# Facebook Login Redirection Data Handling?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am studying Facebook Graph API. Facebook Login Button is successfully set up and it redirects to another page. At the same php file where i put the code of login button, i gathered the data of the user using the callback function.

The question is, when I get redirected to another page, how will the data be passed on to that another page? Can I already use the $_GET or $_POST method?

Here is my callback function located in index.php:

```
function statusChangeCallback(response){
       if(response.status === 'connected'){
         FB.api("/me?fields=id,name",function(response){
             document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = 'ID: ' + response.id + '<br>' + 'Name: ' + response.name;
           });

         //window.location.href = 'https://localhost/gsn2/Home.php'
         console.log("success");
       }else{
           document.getElementById('container')
       }
   }
```

Note: the site redirects to home.php
There is no form where i can put action="home.php" so that i can use $_GET or $_POST. How can I access that to another page?

Comment: why redirect? just use FB.login and stay on the same page. you are making it more complicated for yourself.

Comment: you need to redirect so that you can go to the user's profile after loggin in. when you go to the same page, nothing will happen.

Comment: well, you can also redirect with javascript after login, no problem there.

Comment: you're not being useful

Comment: you are using the js sdk already, so why not use it for the login (including redirecteion after login) too? i don´t see where that is not helpful, i am doing this since many years without any issues. again, you are making it more complicated for yourself.

Comment: you don't seem to understand my question

Comment: do you know about FB.getLoginStatus? If not, you should check it out. You don´t need to "pass data around".